# Not a single-group group function oracle sum with subquery sum

Tags: mysql, oracle, group-by, subquery

Why does this query have an error in Oracle, but is correct in MySQL?

```
SELECT (select sum(total)
FROM   invoices) + sum(total)
FROM invoices;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why this query have an error in oracle and in mysql is correct

Because MySQL is kind of permissive about mixing aggregate and non-aggregate columns.

To quote [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html):

> In standard SQL, a query that includes a GROUP BY clause cannot refer to nonaggregated columns in the select list that are not named in the GROUP BY clause.
>
> [...]
>
> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause.
>
> [...]
>
> this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group. **The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate**.

Answer (score 0):

`(select sum(total) FROM invoices)` is an expression, it's not an aggregate function and it doesn't exist in GROUP BY (actually you cannot use subqueries in GROUP BY)

So you are trying to mix aggregate and none-aggregate expressions together.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a working version in Oracle, you could do:

```
select sum(total) + sum(total)
from invoices;
```

Comment: Which would be a better solution in MySQL as well.